# how to check each asp checkbox in gridview

Tags: gridview, checkbox, each, checked

```
<asp:GridView ID="science_tab" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"   ShowHeader="false" class="subjects_tab">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate> 
    <asp:CheckBox ID="sciencefees_check" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("sub_name") %>' ></asp:CheckBox><%-- i tried binding the text to custom name like Text="anyname" --%>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<label class="rsperhr" for="sciencefees_text">Rupees</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="sciencefees_text" runat="server" Width="40px"  ></asp:TextBox>
    <label class="rsperhr" for="sciencefees_text">Per Hour</label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and a label and button..

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

this is the on button onclick event:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < science_tab.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
          GridViewRow row = science_tab.Rows[i];
          bool isChecked = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("sciencefees_check")).Checked;
          if (isChecked)
          {
               Label1.Text += i + " checked  ";
          }
          else
          Label1.Text += i + " unchecked  ";
      }
}
```

does not matter how many checkboxes i check if statement always goes  for false...
label1.Text gives the result 0 unchecked 1 unchecked 2 unchecked ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(GridViewRow gvr in science_tab.Rows)
    {
        if (((CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("sciencefees_check")).Checked == true)
        {
            Response.Write("I am True");//Do Something
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("I am False");  //Do Something  //Label1.Text = " unchecked  ";
        }
    }
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

//Test Data for binding...
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col2", typeof(string)));
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(new string[]{string.Empty, i.ToString()});
    }
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

    science_tab.DataSource = dt;
    science_tab.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: How you are binding the checkbox, while loading the gridview.

Comment: SqlCommand computerlanguagestab_com = new SqlCommand("select *     from tutions_subjects where category ='Computer'", connection);
    read = computerlanguagestab_com.ExecuteReader();
    computerlanguages_tab.DataSource = read;
    computerlanguages_tab.DataBind();
    read.Close();

    connection.Close(); }

Comment: checkbox are bound to the gridview under page load function. i have put a button in the last to check each checkbox but same thing happens. i have tried every possibility plz help try something same yourself to check plz plz help...

Comment: hey, i found the solution. It was all about post back. whenever i pressed the button to check the checked items in gridview the page_load function is triggered which again binds all the checkedboxes to gridview all of whose checked property is false. So i put the gridview binding stuff into [If (!Ispostback) {stuff} ] which forbids the binding again... anyhow thanks for helping me Anna.P.